# EF code first always Insert a new child records instead of linking it with 1:1 relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these classes

```
public class Subdist
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubdistPIC> SubdistPICs { get; set; }
}

public class SubdistPIC
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Subdist Subdist { get; set; }
    public virtual PIC PIC { get; set; }
}

public class PIC
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

when I called this method

```
    public void InsertSubdist(Subdist obj)
    {
        _uow.Subdist.Add(obj);
        _uow.Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

it will automatically insert a new PIC instead of just linking it with 1:1 relationship. For example :

If my PIC table has these records

```
PIC
ID  Name    Active
1   Tommy   1
2   Joel    1
3   Ellie   1
```

it will now have

```
PIC
ID  Name    Active
1   Tommy   1
2   Joel    1
3   Ellie   1
4   Tommy   1
5   Joel    1
6   Ellie   1

SubdistPIC
ID  PIC_ID Subdist_ID
1   5      1
2   4      1
3   6      1
```

What I want is :

```
PIC
ID  Name    Active
1   Tommy   1
2   Joel    1
3   Ellie   1

SubdistPIC
ID  PIC_ID Subdist_ID
1   1      1
2   2      1
3   3      1
```

Any idea how to achieve this? I'm new to EF

Comment: Have you specified any mappings? You have PIC_ID in your SubdistPIC table, but in one-to-one relationship it is not needed, ID of SubdistPIC must be ID of PIC

Comment: You will most likely have to either convert to Sequences, or use a transaction and insert each set separately so you can match up the `id` of the other.